React Router: Persisting Previous Route After Logout Without Using LocalStorage
Description:
I'm working on a React project where I need to persist the previous route a user was on even after they log out, without using localStorage. I'm using React Router v6 and Apollo Client for state management and GraphQL queries. Currently, when a user logs out, the previous route resets to a default value ("/") instead of retaining the last accessed route.
Problem:
The previousRouteRef resets to the default value ("/") when the user logs out, and I need it to retain the last accessed route.
Expected Behavior:
I expected previousRouteRef.current to hold the last accessed route and remain unchanged after the user logs out. This way, when the user logs back in, I could use the stored route to redirect them back to where they were before logging out.
Observations:
I noticed that the RoutesWrapper component re-renders three times during the logout process. I suspect that this repeated rendering may be causing previousRouteRef to reset to its default value ("/") instead of retaining the last accessed route.
Render Count:
I added a counter to track the number of times RoutesWrapper renders and logged the value of previousRouteRef during each render. The logs confirm that previousRouteRef.current is reset to the default route path after the re-renders.
Files Involved:
RoutesWrapper.js
This component manages the routing and checks if the user is logged in or not. It contains previousRouteRef that should persist the last route accessed.
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import LineWobbleLoader from "@/components/customs/helpers/page-loader";
import useAuthRedirect from "@/hooks/use-auth-redirect";
import MainLayout from "@/layout/main-layout";
import PageLayout from "@/layout/page-layout";
import ForgotPassword from "@/pages/auth-form/login/forgot-password-page";
import { Login } from "@/pages/auth-form/login/login";
import ResetPassword from "@/pages/auth-form/login/reset-password";
import { SignUp } from "@/pages/auth-form/signup/signup";
import SignUpVerify from "@/pages/auth-form/signup/signup-verify";
import AddContact from "@/pages/contacts/add-contact";
import Contacts from "@/pages/contacts/contacts";
import Dashboard from "@/pages/dashboard/dashboard";
import MessageTemplate from "@/pages/messages/message-templates";
import SetupPage from "@/pages/setup/setup-page";
import SuccessPage from "@/pages/success/success-page";
import CreateTemplate from "@/pages/templates/add-template";
import { Navigate, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

function RoutesWrapper() {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const previousRouteRef = useRef<string>("/");
  const renderCount = useRef(0);
  
  const { meData, whatsappData, meLoading, whatsappLoading, refetchMe } =
    useAuthRedirect({ isLoggedIn });

  renderCount.current += 1;
  console.log(`RoutesWrapper render count: ${renderCount.current}`);

  useEffect(() => {
    refetchMe();
  }, [isLoggedIn, refetchMe]);

  if (meLoading || whatsappLoading) {
    return (
      <div className="h-screen flex justify-center items-center">
        <LineWobbleLoader />
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Routes>
      {!meData ? (
        <>
          <Route path="/" element={<Login setIsLoggedIn={setIsLoggedIn} previousRouteRef={previousRouteRef} />} />
          <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp />} />
          <Route path="/forgot-password" element={<ForgotPassword />} />
          <Route path="/reset-password" element={<ResetPassword />} />
          <Route path="/success-page" element={<SuccessPage />} />
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <Route path="/" element={whatsappData?.getWhatsApp?.business ? <Navigate to="/contacts" replace /> : <Navigate to="/setup" replace />} />
          <Route path="/setup" element={<SetupPage setIsLoggedIn={setIsLoggedIn} previousRouteRef={previousRouteRef} />} />
          <Route element={<PageLayout />}>
            {whatsappData?.getWhatsApp?.business ? (
              <Route element={<MainLayout previousRouteRef={previousRouteRef} meData={meData.me} setIsLoggedIn={setIsLoggedIn} />}>
                <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
                <Route path="/contacts" element={<Contacts />} />
                <Route path="/addcontact" element={<AddContact />} />
                <Route path="/templates" element={<CreateTemplate />} />
                <Route path="/newtemplate" element={<MessageTemplate />} />
                <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" replace />} />
              </Route>
            ) : (
              <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/setup" replace />} />
            )}
          </Route>
        </>
      )}
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default RoutesWrapper;



useLogout.js
This hook handles the logout process and should set previousRouteRef to the current pathname before logging out.
import { useMutation } from "@apollo/client";
import { LOGOUT } from "@/services/gpl/mutations";

const useLogout = ({ setIsLoggedIn, previousRouteRef }) => {
  const [logout] = useMutation(LOGOUT);

  const handleLogout = () => {
    previousRouteRef.current = window.location.pathname; // Persisting the current route
    logout()
      .then(() => {
        setIsLoggedIn(false);
        window.location.href = "/";
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error("Logout error:", error);
      });
  };

  return { handleLogout };
};

export default useLogout;


useLogin.tsx
import { useLazyQuery, useApolloClient } from "@apollo/client";
import { LOGIN, ME } from "@/services/gpl/queries";
import { useToast } from "@/components/ui/use-toast";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

interface LoginInput {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

type Props = {
  setIsLoggedIn: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
  previousRouteRef: React.MutableRefObject<string>;
};

const useLogin = ({ setIsLoggedIn, previousRouteRef }: Props) => {
  const { toast } = useToast();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const client = useApolloClient();
  const [login, { loading, error, data }] = useLazyQuery(LOGIN);

  const handleLogin = (loginInput: LoginInput) => {
    login({ variables: { login: loginInput } })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data?.login) {
          setIsLoggedIn(true);
          const cachedMeData = client.readQuery({ query: ME });
          if (cachedMeData && cachedMeData.me) {
            if (cachedMeData.me.email === response.data.login.email) {
              navigate(previousRouteRef.current || "/contacts");
              return;
            }
          }
          navigate("/contacts");
        } else {
          toast({
            title: "Failed",
            description: error?.message,
            className: "text-red-600 border-red-600",
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        toast({
          description: "Invalid email or password",
          className: "text-red-600 border-red-600",
        });
      });
  };

  return {
    loading,
    error,
    data,
    handleLogin,
  };
};

export default useLogin;


What I Tried:
Using useRef for previousRouteRef: I initialized previousRouteRef using useRef to store the last accessed route before logging out. However, after logging out, this value resets to the default ("/") instead of persisting.
Setting previousRouteRef in handleLogout: I attempted to set previousRouteRef.current to window.location.pathname right before logging out in the handleLogout function. Despite this, the value still resets to the default route.
Debugging Render Count: I added console logs to track the render count of my RoutesWrapper component and the value of previousRouteRef. I observed that the component re-renders multiple times during the logout process, which may be affecting the state.

You probably ought to use localStorage if you really wanted to "persist" the previously accessed route URL, but the issue I see is in your logout handler where you do a hard redirect back to "/", i.e. window.location.href = "/";, which necessarily reloads the page, and thus remounts the entire React app. The previousRouteRef will be initialized to "/".
I suggest using the useNavigate hook and issue a client-side redirect back to the home page.
Example:
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useMutation } from "@apollo/client";
import { LOGOUT } from "@/services/gpl/mutations";

const useLogout = ({ setIsLoggedIn, previousRouteRef }) => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [logout] = useMutation(LOGOUT);

  const handleLogout = async () => {
    previousRouteRef.current = pathname; // Persisting the current route

    try {
      await logout();
      setIsLoggedIn(false);
      navigate("/", { replace: true });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Logout error:", error);
    };
  };

  return { handleLogout };
};

export default useLogout;

This should keep the app mounted and not reset the previousRouteRef value.

Thank you for your suggestion regarding the use of useNavigate for client-side redirection instead of using window.location.href. However, I tried implementing your approach, and I'm still encountering issues.
Problems Encountered:
Logout Functionality: After implementing this change, I found that the user is not being logged out successfully. The logout mutation is being called, but it doesn’t seem to complete as expected.
Navigation Issues:
The application does not navigate to the "/" route after a successful logout, which was my primary goal.

@iddiMsangi It's entirely possible you have other issues in the code we can't see. What does logout do? Is there some error in the mutation that prevents the rest of the asynchronous code from processing? Is there a thrown error or rejected Promise and the flow goes into the catch block? How far into the handleLogout function can you trace through?

I can confirm that the logout mutation is working correctly. I have verified its execution in the network tab, and it completes successfully without any errors.
However, the issue arises after the logout completes, specifically with the navigation part of the code.I have checked for any console errors, but none appear during the logout process.
It seems that the flow of execution is not reaching the navigate call after the logout promise resolves, which is where I am encountering the problem.

@iddiMsangi If you are not getting past await logout(); then I'd arguably say it's not completing successfully as expected. If you drop a console.log statement after await logout(); do you see it output? Do you mind editing your post to include a complete [mcve] of the code you are using, from the router all the way through to where these hooks are running, and everything between?
